# Is there any restriction for target images on EasyAR?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, easyar

I have had problem with target images using EasyAR. I am developing my app on Unity. All ImageTarget's work fine and all target images are correctly recognized by the app when I run it on Unity. However, when I deploy the app to my Android phone, 2 of my target images can't get recognized. I have a total of 4 images in this app to be recognized: 2 photos of people, which work fine on PC and Android, and 2 pictures with white background, which work fine on PC but not on Android. You can see the not working images [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aimf8gujO73hgx7sKddScX8zTOMd).

I have tried resizing and inverting colors for those images, but it did not work. I also tried to set the ImageTarget to use a different image (a picture of myself, in this case) and it worked fine, which means the problem is not in the configuration of the ImageTarget.

So, my question is, do you know if there is any restriction for target images that would explain why my images are working on PC but not on Android? If not, can you guys help me figure out what is wrong with my app? I have been stuck in this problem for a long time!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are "difficult to detect" maybe ([Reco difficulty](https://www.easyar.com/doc/EasyAR%20CRS/api/farmer-grade.html)) so I think, for make things easier you can add some frame around or line at bottom at the image. The reason of difference between could be the quarlity of cameras and/or speed of processor.

Also see [Best practice for adding new target image](https://www.easyar.com/doc/EasyAR%20CRS/newtarget.html)